# Is it possible to manage tabs only within the single window in split mode?

Tags: neovim, terminal, split

Here is my situation. I launch tmux on iTerm2 and then split the window vertically (left and right), then make the right side of the window split horizontally. So now, there are 3 windows, one big at the left and two small at the right.

Then, I launch neovim on the large window at the left side. This is my usual workflow but I found it is more comfortable to use neovim's terminal mode, instead of the tmux. So I rather put two terminal windows at the right side of the window.

But then, if I manage buffers at tabs, the only one tab shows two terminal windows at the right; all the other tabs only show one buffer until and unless I split the window and launch the terminal mode there.

What I rather want to do is use two terminal mode at the right and whatever files at the left, which are managed by tabs and can be switched easily, with the two terminal windows are always fixed there. Is this possible in neovim?

Comment: Do you want the same two terminal buffers for every tab or separate terminal buffers for each tab?

Comment: @EnanAjmain Same terminal buffers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [wintabs](https://github.com/zefei/vim-wintabs). They claim to help you manage buffers on a per window basis.